# How to use Video MEM fasm assembly

Tags: assembly, video, x86, osdev, fasm

I am writing an OS on fasm assembly, R-OS, and I want to know, how to use video memory without bios. current OSs as Windows or MacOS making me create video system in kernel, and I dunt know how. Help plz.

boot.asm:

```
org 0x7C00

xor ax, ax
mov ds, ax
mov es, ax
mov ss, ax
mov sp, 0,7C00
cld

mov ax, 0x03
int 0x10

mov si, boot_msg
call printf

mov al, 0x04
mov bx, 0x7E00
mov cx, 0x0002
mov dh, 0x00
call disk_read

mov ax, 0x7E0
mov ds, ax
mov es, ax
mov sp, 0x7E00
jmp 0x7E0:0x0000

include 'disk.asm'
include 'printh.asm'

times 510-$+$$ db 0x00
dw 0xAA55

include 'kernel.asm'

times 65536-512-$+$$ db 0x00
```

kernel.asm:

```
org 0x7E00

mov ax, 0x4F02
mov bx, 0x101
int 0x10
mov ah, 0x0C
mov al, 0x0F
mov cx, 0x10
mov dx, 0x10
int 0x10

msg0 db 'R-OS', 0x00

raf dd 0
wax dw 0
wah db 0
wal db 0
buff db 1024 dup (?)

jmp end2048

end2048:
cli
hlt
jmp $-2
times 2048-$+$$ db 0x00
```

disk.asm have just kernel load func
and printh.asm just printf and printh
funcs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not every BIOS will work for an extended video mode like 101h! The BIOS.WritePixel function 0Ch normally only operates on the LEGACY video modes. Those are the video modes whose number ranges from 0 to 19.
The video mode 101h is a 640x480 256-color VESA defined video mode. Writing pixels on the screen without using BIOS will require learning a lot about VESA, linear frame buffers, bank switching, etc.

You are in the process of creating an OS. And you are at the very start of it. I think you should keep it as simple as possible in this stage, and select a legacy video mode that is easy to work with: the 320x200 256-color video mode.
An operating system is so much more than its screen, so invest most of your time in the other stuff and leave the niceties of the output screen for last. You'll thank me for it later. Many people before have lost themselves writing beautiful splashscreens and special effects, but failing to even provide an elementary input line (prompt).

This is an example of how you put a single pixel on the 320x200 256-color screen directly. The address for the pixel is calculated from

```
AddressInVideoBuffer = (Y * BytesPerScanline) + X
```

```
  mov  ax, 0013h   ; BIOS.SetVideoMode 320x200x8
  int  10h

  ...

  ; Puts a green dot in the middle of the screen
  mov  cl, 2       ; Color = Green
  mov  bx, 100     ; Y
  mov  ax, 160     ; X
  call PutPixel

  ...

; IN (ax,bx,cl) OUT () MOD (ax)
PutPixel:
  push ds bx       ; Preserve registers, allow AX to get clobbered
  imul bx, 320       ; Y * BytesPerScanline
  add  bx, ax        ; + X
  mov  ax, 0xA000    ; VideoBuffer
  mov  ds, ax
  mov  [bx], cl      ; Write the color from CL
  pop  bx ds         ; Restore registers
  ret
```

Here's another code that uses nested loops to fill a rectangular area of the screen with some color:

```
; IN (ax,bx,cl,si,di)
; AX is UpperLeftX, BX is UpperLeftY, CL is Color, SI is Width, DI is Height
PaintRectangle:
  push ds bx di       ; Preserve registers, allow AX to get clobbered
  imul bx, 320        ; UpperLeftY * BytesPerScanline
  add  bx, ax         ; + UpperLeftX
  mov  ax, 0xA000     ; VideoBuffer
  mov  ds, ax
.OuterLoop:
  push si             ; (1)
.InnerLoop:
  dec  si
  mov  [bx+si], cl    ; Write the color from CL
  jnz  .InnerLoop
  pop  si             ; (1)
  add  bx, 320        ; Move to next scanline (line below)
  dec  di             ; Decrement Height
  jnz  .OuterLoop
  pop  di bx ds       ; Restore registers
  ret
```

Comment: oh, thank you, just i want to do modern OS with enough minimal features, but your words sonds like expert's, and i will trust it.

Comment: and one more, can you say me, how i can to fill zone of the screen with color (for e.g., white)?

Comment: @VåñøČhêt That would require writing some nested loops. I'll see that I can add an example to my answer.

Comment: your code doesn't work. i tryed to compile and run it, but qemu (already no bochs) ignored it

Comment: @VåñøČhêt Wouldn't that rather depend on *how* you inserted the new code in the whole of your project? Feel free to post a new question but be sure to include all of your code this time.

Comment: oka, wait plz  .