# write videosystem in fasm assembly

Tags: assembly, kernel, osdev, fasm, video-memory

i am writing an os in fasm assembly and faced with problem - bios videoservices works too slow. i already published similar question, but it is more that questin type as "how to write pixel to videomemory", now i have to draw some geometrical primitives. and i dunt have any ideas about how i can realise it. help, plz

code

*boot.asm*:

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;  TEXT  ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
    org 0x7C00

    xor ax, ax
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov ss, ax
    mov sp, 0x7C00
    cld

    mov ax, 0x03

    int 0x10

    mov si, boot_msg
    call printf

    mov al, 8704/512   ; sector to read
    mov bx, 0x7E00     ; destination
    mov cx, 0x0002     ; cylinder:sector
    mov dh, 0x00       ; head
    call disk_read

    mov ax, 0x7E0
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov sp, 0x7E00
    jmp 0x7E0:0x0000
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;  DATA  ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
    include 'disk.asm'
    include 'printh.asm'

    boot_msg db 'R-OS bootloader                                                                 ',\
            'R-OS kernel CHS: 0x00/0x00/0x02                                                 ',\
            "Testing first MB of ROM... Fine, All that need free. kernel loading to 0x7E00   ", 0x00
    disk_err db 'Disk error, errcode ', 0x00

    times 510-$+$$ db 0x00
    dw 0xAA55
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;  TEXT 0x200  ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
    include 'kernel.asm'
    include 'fs.asm'
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
    times 65024-$+$$ db 0x00
```

*kernel.asm*:

```
    org 0x7E00
    mov [bootdev], dl
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;  Macroses
macro pixel c, x, y {
    pusha
    mov al, c
    mov cx, x
    mov dx, y
    call __pixel
    popa
}
macro pix c, x, y {
    pusha
    mov dl, c
    mov ax, x
    mov bx, y
    call __putpix
    popa
}
macro zone c, x, y, w, h {
    pusha
    mov al, c
    mov cx, x
    mov dx, y
    mov si, w
    mov di, h
    call __zone2
    popa
}
macro rect c, x, y, w, h {
    mov cl, c
    mov ax, x
    mov bx, y
    mov si, w+x
    mov di, h+y
    call __rect
}
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;  Kernel
    mov   ah,     0x00
    mov   al,     0x13
    int   0x10
    zone  0x09,   0,      0,     32,     20
    int   0x10
    pix 0x01, 33, 21
    rect  0x0C,   10,      10,     10,     10
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;  Text core


    jmp __footer
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;  Bss
    buffer  db 1024 dup (?)
    bootdev db 0x00
    reg0    dw 0x0000
    reg8    dw 0x0000
    hexstr  db '0x0000', 0x00
    rstr    db 'R-OS Kernel', 0x00
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;  Funcs
__pixel:
    mov ah, 0x0C
    int 0x10
    ret
__fill:
    mov ah, 0x0C
    mov cx, 0x00
    mov dx, 0x00
.__:
    inc dx
    cmp dx, 200-1
    int 0x10
    call ._
    jmp .__
._:
    inc cx
    cmp cx, 320-1
    int 0x10
    cmp di, 0
    je ._g
    cmp di, 0
    jne ._l
    je ._onemore
    jmp ._
._onemore:
    cmp dx, 200-1
    je ._end
    jmp .__
._end:
    ret
._g:
    inc al
    cmp al, 0x0F
    jge ._21
    ret
._l:
    dec al
    cmp al, 0x00
    jle ._20
    ret
._21:
    mov di, 0x01
    ret
._20:
    mov di, 0x00
    ret
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;  Bitmap font func

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;  Fill func
__zone2:
    mov ah, 0x0C
    int 0x10
    mov bx, cx
    mov bp, dx
    jmp ._x
._x:
    mov dx, bp
    cmp cx, si
    je ._e
    inc cx
    cmp cx, [si+1]
    jne ._y
._y:
    cmp dx, di
    je ._x
    inc dx
    pusha
    dec cx
    dec dx
    ;int 0x10
    pix al, cx, dx
    popa
    jmp ._y
._e:
    ret
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;  putpix func
__putpix:
    push    ds    bx
    imul    bx,   320
    add bx,   ax
    mov ax,   0xA000
    mov ds,   ax
    mov byte  [bx],    cl
    pop bx    ds
    ret
__rect:
    push    ds    bx       di
    imul    bx,   320
    add bx,   ax
    mov ax,   0xA000
    mov ds,   ax
.__:
    push    si
    jmp ._
._:
    dec si
    mov [bx+si],       cl
    jnz ._
    pop si
    add bx,   320
    dec di
    jnz .__
    pop di    bx       ds
    ret
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;  Footer
__footer:
    cli
    hlt
    jmp $-2
    times 8704-$+$$ db 0x00
```

Comment: Sep Roland say me as i can feel rectangle, but it is doesn't work. it is addes to rectangle color pattern on top of it.

Comment: Drawing geometric primitives is a too broad topic. And is marginally related to assembly and the VGA memory interface. The same algorithms would work, say, for an HTML5 canvas (granted that there's room for optimization in assembly). What geometrical primitives do you want to draw? Polygons? Circles? Rhombus? Trapezius? Do you want to stroke them or fill them? None of the hundreds of algorithms for geometric drawings present on SO and the Internet worked for you? Did they work partially? Don't just post a dump of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the *PaintRectangle* code that I gave to you in a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69395279/how-to-use-video-mem-fasm-assembly/69396634#69396634), the `SI` register is the **width** and the `DI` register is the **height**. My code works correct, but in todays question you are loading these registers with another (X,Y) for the point just outside of the LowerRight corner!

> ```
> macro rect c, x, y, w, h {
>   mov cl, c
>   mov ax, x
>   mov bx, y
>   mov si, w+x    <<<<< WRONG, don't add +x
>   mov di, h+y    <<<<< WRONG, don't add +y
>   call __rect
> }
> ```

And the *pix* macro loads the color into the wrong register! You must use `CL`.

> ```
> macro pix c, x, y {
>   pusha
>   mov dl, c   <<<<< WRONG, use `CL`
>   mov ax, x
>   mov bx, y
>   call __putpix
>   popa
> }
> ```

### Want some more geometrical primitives?

The *PaintRectangle* code can draw an horizontal line. Just specify a height of 1 in `DI`.
The *PaintRectangle* code can draw a vertical line. Just specify a width of 1 in `SI`.
From a recent codereview post of mine [81-variations-of-the-rounded-rectangle](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/261067/81-variations-of-the-rounded-rectangle) you can learn how to draw any rectangle you like. You can even make that  code draw a circle! After all, a full circle is nothing more than all 4 convex corners coming together. (Tip: use a rectangle that is a square)

### Conclusion

Stop using macros. You're complicating matters and you're not yet up to the task. Currently you're making too many `call`s and you're too liberal with `pusha` and `popa` instructions.
Much of the rest of this code is using BIOS - that you didn't want to use in the first place! Stick with the 2 codes *PutPixel* and *PaintRectangle*, study carefully **how** they work, and then derive your own code from them.

Comment: ok, how i can to draw unfilled rectangle or diagonal line? circle? ellipse? i want to do really good vudeo system, but i very bad wuth working in registers, it just making my brain as water.

Answer (score -2):

Usually gpus have a shared memory. Write into directly instead bioses calls. Some years ago the video memory was 0A000h. You have also
__putpix. It should be much faster than bios call

Comment: i know it, but how i can to draw some geometry primitives using this? __rect drawing linear pattern of colors on top of rect, so it doesn't work. question about geometrical primitives.

Comment: __rect use ax,bx,si,di and cl respectively for x,y, width,height and color. Is it not working? For square use __rect with width=height. For circle use tondies  you try sqrt(x*x+y*y) > width or width"width < xx+yy

Comment: ...remove also int 10h after zone 0x9... maybe it is damaging registers

Comment: try this code for a circle `main:
 mov   ah,     0x00
 mov   al,     0x13
 int   10h
    mov ax, 30
    mov bx, 30
    mov si, 20
    call __tondies

 ret

__tondies:
 push ds di
    imul bx, 320
    add bx, ax
    mov ax, 0xA000
    mov ds, ax
    mov cx,si
    imul cx,cx
    sal si,1
    mov di,si
.aa:
    push si
.aaa:
 mov ax,si
 sub ax,20
 imul ax,ax
 mov dx,di
 sub dx,20
 imul dx,dx
 add ax,dx
 cmp ax,cx
 jg .aaaa
 mov byte  [bx+si],10
.aaaa:
 dec si
 jnz .aaa
.c:
 add bx,320
 pop si
 dec di
 jnz .aa
.b:
    pop di ds
 ret
`

Comment: @Lino: [edit] your answer to include code blocks.  Non-trivial amounts of code in comments are a jumbled mess

Comment: The question is closed. I am very busy for answer quickly

Comment: @Lino, i know, tondies is not bad method, but it doesn't work with small radiuses. for e.g., r=5 doesn't work.